# how to show that $f_n \uparrow f$

Tags: calculus

How to show that $f_n \uparrow f$ where 
$$f_n(x)=\min\left(\frac{\lfloor 2^nf(x)\rfloor}{2^n},n\right)$$
It is clear to me that $f_n(x) \leq f(x)$
But how do I show that the limit is indeed  $f$ ?

My argument. It is clear that as n increases $\lfloor 2^nf(x)\rfloor$ increases but is always less than $f(x)$ but dividing it by $2^n $ makes it very close or equal to $f(x)$

I mean if I forget about $n$ for a second then $\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{\lfloor 2^nf(x) \rfloor}{2^n} \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^nf(x)-1}{2^n}=f(x)$

The same is true for $ \liminf_{n \to  \infty }f_n(x) \geq f(x)$

And therefore $f \uparrow f$

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argumentation is valid, but I don't know why you introduce a liminf.

For every real number $x$ the inequality $x - 1 \le \lfloor x \rfloor \le x$ holds. In this case:
$$f(x) - 2^{-n} = \frac{2^nf(x) - 1}{2^n} \le \frac{\lfloor 2^n f(x) \rfloor}{2^n} \le \frac{2^nf(x)}{2^n} = f(x)$$

The sandwich theorem now implies $\frac{\lfloor 2^n f(x) \rfloor}{2^n} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} f(x)$. It is easy to see that the minimum doesn't change anything about the limit. Simply choose for each $x$ an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $N > f(x)$ and therefore $f_n(x) = \frac{\lfloor 2^n f(x) \rfloor}{2^n}$ for all $n > N$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I was reading Rick Durett's Probability theory and examples -First Chapter to brush up my measure theory . In the proof of the Lemma 1.4.4 (Let $E_n \uparrow \Omega$ have $\mu(E_n) < \infty $ then $\int_{E_n} f ^n d \mu \uparrow \int f d \mu $ as $n \uparrow \infty $). Now here the author first show that $\int_{E_n} f^n d \mu \leq \int f d \mu$ and then proves that $ \liminf_{n \to  \infty } \int_{E_n} f ^n d \mu \geq \int h d \mu$ where $\int f d \mu$ is defined as the supremum of all integrals of bounded h of finite measure such that $0 \leq h<=f$